# Why does this Ultramarine have red armour?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I've recently treated myself to a Repulsor Executioner tank for Warhammer 40k. The guy on the box is clearly an ultramarine (see his left pauldron) but his armour is red.

My understanding is that Sergeants and Officers in the Ultramarines (and most codex following chapters) paint their helmets red following Guilliman's command at the Battle of Calth when Thiel (a marine under censure) turned out to be right about

> the possibility that astartes could end up fighting astartes

However, this marine appears to have completely red armour. Is there a canonical reason for this or is it simply because the 'Eavy Metal decided it would look cool?

[image: Repulsor Exectutioner Tank]

[image]

Comment: "In the ten millennia since the Battle of Calth, the Sergeants of the Ultramarines and several other Codex-compliant Chapters continue to paint their helmets red to signify the honour accorded to the Astartes who achieve this rank" - however this SM doesn't have a helmet, so maybe the rest of the armour was painted red to represent this?  This is just a guess however.

Comment: Could he be a techmarine? If I remember right they are usually depicted with red armor. I'd be curious if he has Adeptus Mechanicus insignia on his right shoulder.

Comment: @m1ping you're right, i've rotated the image and looked at his other shoulder

Answer (score 24, accepted):

He’s a [Techmarine](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Techmarine). You can see the black and white Adeptus Mechanicus emblem on his chest. Techmarines are often depicted in red armor or with red helmets with chapter insignia on one shoulder and the Adeptus Mechanicus insignia on the other.

Comment: You can also see the Adeptus Mechanicus emblem on his right pauldron (shoulder) as well.

Comment: I'd best crack open my Mephiston Red then!